# Which versions Visual Studio can support the Dafny IDE plugin?

Tags: dafny

Which versions Visual Studio can support the Dafny 1.9.7 IDE plugin?

In particular I'm interested in VS 2015 Community edition since I'd like my students to be able to use it without extra cost.

Answer (score 2):

I have looked in the file [source.extension.vsixmanifest](https://github.com/Microsoft/dafny/blob/master/Source/DafnyExtension/source.extension.vsixmanifest). Where I see the following:

```
<Installation InstalledByMsi="false">
    <InstallationTarget Version="[11.0,15.0)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" />
    <InstallationTarget Version="[14.0,15.0)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community" />
</Installation>
```

Consulting [the documentation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2013/08/08/update-for-extension-authors-vsix-manifest-version-range-attribute/) I read this as Visual Studio Community minimum version inclusive 14.0, maximum version exclusive 15.0. Which I understand to mean it supports any version of visual studio 14. I believe that 14 is the internal version number of Visual Studio 2015.

Putting that all together I think it means that the Dafny extension should install on VisualStudio Community 2015.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried installing the Dafny extension (version 1.9.7 of Dafny) on a few different versions of Visual Studio.  This was on Windows 7. Here is what I learned

- VS 2012 Express for Desktop: No.
- VS 2012 Professional: Yes.
- VS 2012 Premium: Yes (*).
- VS 2013 Community: Yes (*).
- VS 2015 Community: Yes (*).

In each of the cases marked with a (*) I've had problems where the extension has appeared to crash the first time it tried to parse a new Dafny file.  However, shutting down VS and restarting it appeared to solve the problem.